# Setting the navigation item's properties with RBStoryboardLink?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am linking storyboard with [RBStoryboardLink](https://github.com/rob-brown/RBStoryboardLink). When I attempt to modify the current view controller's title with the following code, I don't see any changes:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Foo";
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

With this storyboard linking solution, the view controller is being added as child view controller. Its properties are only copied one time when the segue actually takes place.

For example in SSUStoryboardLink.m, the following code is executed in awakeFromNib:

```
...
navItem.title = linkedNavItem.title;
navItem.titleView = linkedNavItem.titleView;
navItem.prompt = linkedNavItem.prompt;
navItem.hidesBackButton = linkedNavItem.hidesBackButton;
navItem.backBarButtonItem = linkedNavItem.backBarButtonItem;
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = linkedNavItem.rightBarButtonItem;
...
```

In order to set properties, you must set them on the parent view controller:

```
self.parentViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method

```
- (UIViewController *)rbsl_targetViewController
```

This will make sure, that you'll actually get the RBStoryboardLink that contains your view controller.

So, in your case

```
#import "UIViewController+RBStoryboardLink.h"

self.rbsl_targetViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Foo";
```

[Here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/RBStoryboardLink/0.1.4/Categories/UIViewController+RBStoryboardLink.html) is the documentation.